# the problem with alien attack..from foundation game design with html and javascript

Tags: javascript

```css
*
{
  font-family: emulogic;  
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

@font-face 
{
  font-family: emulogic;
  src: url("../fonts/emulogic.ttf");
  
  /*
  
  Note: Firefox requires that the font file
  be in the same folder as the CSS file.
  If you are using Firefox, copy the emulogic.ttf font
  into the src folder and use this src property:
  
  src: url("../fonts/emulogic.ttf");
  
  */
  
}


h1
{
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #FFBF00;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  
  text-shadow: 3px 3px lime;
  
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1px #000;
  -moz-text-stroke: 1px #000;
  text-stroke: 1px #000;
}

p
{
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  color: #FFBF00;
}

input
{
  font-size: 15px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #FFBF00;
  width: 75px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 1px solid lime;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;    
}

button
{
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #FFBF00;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 2px solid lime;
    
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;  
  background: black;
    
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

button:hover
{
  background-color: #FFBF00;
  color: #000;
}

button:active
{
  background-color: #9e7606;
  color: #000;
}

#game
{
  margin: 0px auto;
  width: 330px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 15px;
  border: black;  
  
  background:-webkit-linear-gradient(300deg, #588063, #000);
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #588063, #000);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #588063, #000);
    
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;    
}

#stage
{
  margin: 0px auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
    position: relative;
    
  -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: 1px solid lime;
}

#background
{
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/n0DkPx2/background.png);
}

#cannon
{
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 270px;
  left: 140px;
  background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/6wghWkq/cannon.png);
}

#alien
{
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 80px;
  background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/7nx5Kxm/alien.png);
}

#missile
{
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 240px;
  left: 145px;
  background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/qRTtRvB/missile.png);
}

#explosion
{
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/cc4mwW2/explosion.png);
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Alien Attack</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="alienAttack.css">

<section id="game">

<h1>Alien Attack!</h1>

<div id="stage">
  <div id="background"></div>
  <div id="cannon"></div>
  <div id="missile"></div>
  <div id="alien"></div>
  <div id="explosion"></div>
</div>

<p id="output">Enter the X and Y position (0-300), then click fire.</p>
<input id="inputX" type="text" placeholder="X…" autofocus> 
<input id="inputY" type="text" placeholder="Y…"> 
<button>fire!</button>

</section>
    
<script>

//Game variables
var alienX = Math.floor(Math.random() * 280);
var alienY = 20;
var guessX = 0;
var guessY = 0;
var shotsRemaining = 8;
var shotsMade = 0;
var gameState = "";
var gameWon = false;

//The game objects
var cannon = document.querySelector("#cannon");
var alien = document.querySelector("#alien");
var missile = document.querySelector("#missile");
var explosion = document.querySelector("#explosion");

//The input and output fields
var inputX = document.querySelector("#inputX");
var inputY = document.querySelector("#inputY");
var output = document.querySelector("#output");

//The button
var button = document.querySelector("button");
button.style.cursor = "pointer";
button.addEventListener("click", clickHandler, false);

//Listen for enter key presses
window.addEventListener("keydown", keydownHandler, false);

function clickHandler()
{
  validateInput();
}

function keydownHandler(event)
{
  if(event.keyCode === 13)
  {
    validateInput();
  }
}

function validateInput()
{
  guessX = parseInt(inputX.value);
  guessY = parseInt(inputY.value);
  
  if(isNaN(guessX) || isNaN(guessY) )
  {
    output.innerHTML = "Please enter a number.";
  }
  else if(guessX > 300 || guessY > 300)
  {
    output.innerHTML = "Please enter a number less than 300.";
  }
  else
  {
    playGame();
  }
}

function render()
{
  //Position the alien
  alien.style.left = alienX + "px";
  alien.style.top = alienY + "px";
  
  //Position the cannon
  cannon.style.left = guessX + "px";
  
  //Position the missile
  missile.style.left = guessX + "px";
  missile.style.top = guessY + "px";
  
  //display the explosion and hide the 
  //alien if it's been destroyed
  if(gameWon)
  {
    //Display the explosion
    explosion.style.display = "block";
    explosion.style.left = alienX + "px";
    explosion.style.top = alienY + "px";
    
    //Hide the alien
    alien.style.display = "none";
    
    //Hide the missile
    missile.style.display = "none";
  }
}


function playGame()
{
  shotsRemaining = shotsRemaining - 1;
  shotsMade = shotsMade + 1;
  gameState 
    = " Shots: " + shotsMade + ", Remaining: " + shotsRemaining;
  
  //Find out whether the player's x and y guesses are inside
  //The alien's area
  
  if(guessX >= alienX && guessX <= alienX + 20)
  {
     //Yes, it's within the X range, so now let's
     //check the Y range
     
     if(guessY >= alienY  && guessY <= alienY + 20)
     {
       //It's in both the X and Y range, so it's a hit!
       gameWon = true;
       endGame();
     }
  }
  else
  {
    output.innerHTML = "Miss!" + "<br>" + gameState;
    
    //Check for the end of the game
    if (shotsRemaining < 1)
    {
      endGame();
    }
  }
  
  //Update the alien's position if the
  //game hasn't yet been won
  
  if(!gameWon)
  {
    //Update the alien's X position
    alienX = Math.floor(Math.random() * 281);
    
    //Add 30 to the new Y position so that
    //the alien moves down
    alienY += 30;
  } 
  
  //Render the new game state
  render();
  console.log("X: " + alienX);
  console.log("Y: " + alienY);
}

function endGame()
{
  if(gameWon)
  {
    output.innerHTML
      = "Hit! You saved the earth!" + "<br>" 
      + "It only took you " + shotsMade + " shots.";
  }
  else
  {
    output.innerHTML
      = "You lost!" + "<br>" 
      + "The earth has been invaded!";
  }
  
  //Disable the button
  button.removeEventListener("click", clickHandler, false);
  button.disabled = true;
  
  //Disable the enter key
  window.removeEventListener("keydown", keydownHandler, false);
  
  //Disable the input fields
  inputX.disabled = true;
  inputY.disabled = true;
}
    
</script>
```

i asked why the game takes a extra click from the mouse to register the explosion after the 1st guess is wrong.. i also found the game doesnt check for negative numbers either to keep the ship in the game stage. and last there seems to be a issue with the image that can clip the alien but not register a hit. so to answer my own question i found that adding -10 in the statment if(guessX >= alienX - 10 && guessX <= alienX + 20) to the check for collision fixes the issue of the images touching but not registering a hit. and for the extra click to register a explosion after the first guess can be fixed by moving the whole check if statements from playgame() function to the render() function this causes the alien to detect more accurate images and to cause a explosion without the need for a extra click after the first guess. and finally by adding
else if(guessx < 0 || guessy < 0){output.innerHTML = "Please enter a number greater than 0.";}
after
else if(guessx > 300 || guessy > 300){output.innerHTML = "Please enter a number less than 300.";}
fixes the bug of letting someone input negative numbers
i also change the value from 300 to 280 the keep the whole image on the stage since the image is 20 pxs wide.
so if your trying to learn from from foundation game design with html and javascript. and are confused by one of the first games consider these problems

Comment: Your src: url("../fonts/emulogic.ttf"); needs the full file path.

Comment: i left that out because i was running the code example on a local host but i dont use the fonts i was just solving the logical errors in the code that i came across